# How to remove the references from table of contents

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies

I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2cm]{geometry} %showframe
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\section*{Abstract}
\section{Introduction}
\newpage
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{references}
\end{document}
```

And when I create the table of contents it adds the "References" in the TOC, how can I remove this to not be included in TOC? So far I have tried something like

`\bibliography*{references}`

Comment: [Welcome](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx) to Tex! Please provide a very useful [MWEB](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4407/how-to-write-a-mweb-minimal-working-example-with-bibliography).

Comment: @Bobyandbob I hope it helps now :)

Comment: You can write this in your preamble: `\usepackage[notbib]tocbibind}`

Comment: @Bernard, it doesn't work!

Comment: @campa: It seems I posted just before the update with the minimal code.

Comment: @Bernard I noticed the package `apacite` is missing. The present code throws a bunch of errors. The package generates the entry in the `toc`. It can be suppressed with `\usepackage[notocbib]{apacite}`.

Comment: @Campa: That's simpler. You should post an answer.

Answer (score 3):

The answer to this questions is the following command:

```
\usepackage[notocbib]{apacite}
```